# Calculating an Integration in R

Tags: r, statistics, integration

I'm self learning R and I keep seeing the mention of Integrals or calculating Integration in R when trawling through google examples. The three books I'm using (Discovering Statistics using R, R's Cookbook, Beginning R) have no mention of calculating these.

I found a couple of questions on here but they're not the same format/direction as this question. Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358738/how-to-calculate-integral-with-r) question didn't provide any information either.

So my query is, how can you calculate one:

[image: integral]

I guess `h(x)` is a uniform in the unit interval?

Given that I have only found "text" and no actual examples of this implementation, I may just dismiss it and move on if you guys can't verify anything. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure whether you're asking the very straightforward question here or not, but

```
f <- function(x) x*(x^5-1)
integrate(f,0,1)
## -0.3571429 with absolute error < 4e-15
```

seems to work fine.  Checking analytically:

```
f_indef <- function(x) x^7/7-x^2/2
f_indef(1)-f_indef(0)
## [1] -0.3571429
```

or for the lazy:

```
library(Ryacas)
(intres <- yacas("Integrate (x) x*(x^5-1)",addSemi=FALSE))
## x^7/7-x^2/2;
```

I can't get `Eval.yacas` to give me anything but `NULL`, though ...

Comment: Ah excellent. Thanks for posting. It's nice to see some code to implement it.